# Using delimiters to parse a square root equation

Tags: java, parsing, double, delimiter

I'm having trouble with using delimiters.

I want to parse a string containing a square root sign. I only want to parse the number, disregarding the square root sign. Why is the code below not working then?

```
double num = Double.parseDouble(display.getText()).useDelimiter("\u221A");
```

That way, if I have my display.getText() = √9.0, my variable num = 9.0. Because I have discarded the square root sign.

Any input into how I can do that? Thank you for the help!

Comment: How is the code not working? What result are you seeing?

Comment: Why don't you just remove the square root sign before you parse this?

Comment: I get a compile error that says double cannot be dereferenced

Comment: Well, yes you do.  Because you're trying to call a method on something that isn't an object.  So instead of trying to call `useDelimiter`, why don't you just remove the square root sign before parsing?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply replace the √ with an empty string

```
double num = Double.parseDouble(display.getText().replace("\u221A", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.replace method and replace the square root . replaceAll accepts a char sequence, so you can use it to replace the character for square root

String numberValue= input.replace("\u221A","");

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I entered this on the command line and it works: `java Square 3√9.03√500√64321√3.14` and it works. :D Basically I used String classes `split()` method to parse the input on the command line. You could do something similar in a GUI with `split()`

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class Square { 


     static public void main(String[] args) { 

    ArrayList<String> aL = new ArrayList<>();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) { 

        aL.add(args[i]);

    } 

    for(int j=0; j<aL.size(); j++) { 

        sb.append(aL.get(j));



    }

    String realS = sb.toString();

    String[] s1 = realS.split("\u221A");


    for(int e=0; e<s1.length; e++) { 
        double num = Double.parseDouble(s1[e]);
        System.out.println("num equals: " + num);
    }

}







    }
```